# Visibility of passed enviroment variables in docker container - misunderstanding

Tags: docker

Let's look at following example:

```
[user@user~]$ sudo docker run -d -e XYZ=123 ubuntu sleep 10000
2543e7235fa9
[user@user~]$ sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 echo test
test
[user@user~]$ sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 echo $XYZ
<empty row>      
[user@user~]$ sudo docker exec -it 2543e7235fa9 bash
root@2543e7235fa9:/# echo $XYZ
123
```

Why did I get `<empty row>` instead of `123` ? 
And why after executing and entering to bash I am able to see `XYZ=123`?

Comment: the `docker` tag is inappropriate, plain `echo $XYZ` would behave the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two things you are missing here are:

1. `docker exec ... <command>` does not run `<command>` in a shell by default, it just runs `<command>` in the container without a shell.

   If you want to run a command in docker in a non-interactive shell, then use:

   ```
   docker exec <container> bash -c '<command>'
   ```

   If `<command>` has more than one word then it needs to be either single-quoted or double-quoted for the entire command to be passed to `bash -c`.

   e.g. `sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 bash -c 'echo $XYZ'`

2. When you do that, there are two shells that matter:

   - the shell you are running `sudo docker exec ...` in (call that "Shell A")
   - the shell that runs inside the container (call that "Shell B").

   If you **don't** backslash-escape or single-quote the `$` in shell A then shell A will interpolate its own value for `$XYZ` (even if it doesn't have one, which returns an empty string).

   So if `XYZ=5` in Shell A, then your `sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 echo $XYZ` is the same as `exec 2543e7235fa9 echo 5` (and there would be no shell B because you didn't tell docker to run `bash -c ...`).

   If you **do** escape or single-quote `$` then it is passed to shell B as-is, and shell B interpolates its value for `$XYZ`.

In other words, use either:

```
sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 bash -c 'echo $XYZ'
```

or

```
sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 bash -c "echo \$XYZ"
```

The single-quoted form is, IMO, easier to understand what it's doing and what you should use most of the time.  No variable interpolation happens inside single-quotes so the command is passed exactly as it is to shell B.

The double-quoted form is useful when you need to pass variables from shell A into shell B.  If you also need to pass a literal `$` than that should be backslash-escaped. e.g. to get shell B to echo shell A's `$ABC` and its own `$XYZ`:

```
sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 bash -c "echo $ABC \$XYZ"
```

If shell A's `$ABC` equals `10` and shell B's `$XYZ` equals 123, then that would output:

```
10 123
```

---

Note: unless `$XYZ` is defined in one of shell B's startup files, or with `docker run -e XYZ=123` as you used in your example (or with `-env-file`), it will not have a value.

Comment: So enviroment variable is passed via cgroup ? (In other words after running process in container (run -e) we can exec another process (which is not child of run process) and we can access to enviroment variables. Yeah?

Comment: No. It's got nothing to do with cgroups, and everything to do with the fact that you've got two shells that will interpolate a variable if they see an unescaped `$` before something that looks like a variable name.  That's just how you pass literal `$` signs (and other characters) to other shells.  You'd do exactly the same thing if `docker` wasn't involved.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I asked about some details of `-e SOME_VARIABLE=123` options. Where this variable is kept ? Some file ? Some namspace ?

Answer (score 1):

because `$XYZ` gets expanded by the shell in which you run the `docker exec` command.  you need to quote it to get the `$XYZ` string inside.

```
sudo docker exec ... echo \$XYZ
```

there really is a misunderstanding - of what parameters are and how they behave in the shell.  when you run

```
any-command $XYZ
```

the `any-command` never sees `$XYZ`.  your shell replaces it with whatever value that parameter has (in that shell).  since you have no parameter named `XYZ` or it's empty, the actual command line you submit to your shell is

```
sudo docker exec 2543e7235fa9 echo
```

Comment: So enviroment variable is passed via cgroup ? (In other words after running process in container (run -e) we can exec another process (which is not child of run process) and we can access to enviroment variables. Yeah?